# Shell script to move files into another directory based on their name

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to Unix shell scripting.  I have a small task of moving files into another directory based on their names.
I have a directory named `Cars` containing .csv files. I have to read the .csv file names, and move each file into another directory based on the filename, as follows:

`BMW_c.csv` must go into the `BMW/c/` directory.
`Mercedes_x.csv` must go into the `Mercedes/x/` directory.

I tried using for and if loop but couldn`t do it till sub directory.

I highly appreciate your help.

Comment: If you've made an attempt, show us what you've tried. Are you having trouble splitting the filenames, creating the (sub)directories, or what? Please [edit] your question to provide more detail.

Comment: As I said before, **[edit] your question**! Don't use the comments to add more detail.

Comment: Yeah I tried by the following way


'for f in *.csv

    if [${filename} = %BMW% ]
       if[%{filename} =%c%]
 do 
     mv file.csv /BMW/c/
       fi
fi

   if [${filename} = %Mercedes% ]
       if[${filename} = %x%]
 do 
     mv file.csv /Mercedes/x/
       fi
fi

     done'

Comment: You see the link in both my previous comments, and the link beneath the question, where it says [edit]? Click it and edit your question. Also, even from the comments it looks like there are a lot of syntax error in your script - I suggest you visit http://shellcheck.net

Comment: @rk_b4u Either you own an exotic car dealership with a non-existent IT budget -- or it's homework... (which is fine, but... we don't want to deprive you of the learning process, it would almost be as if we were cheating you out of something) See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'll meet you half way: Look into the `cut` command to split out your file names into tokens which you can use for directory names.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work

```
for f in *.csv; do
   DIR="$( echo ${f%.*} | tr '_' '/')"
   mkdir -p "./$DIR"
   mv "$f" "$DIR"
done
```

It will read all *.csv files, replace '_' by '/' in the file names (with .csv removed), create the directory and move the file. There will be errors if there are no csv files in the current directory.

Comment: Some suggestions: use lowercase variable names, use double quotes around your shell variables and use `$( )` instead of backticks for command substitutions (not that you really need to use one here).

Comment: `$DIR` needs to be quoted, otherwise it will fail if it contains white spaces

Answer (score -1):

I have done this and tried,it works.If any modifications or enhancements in the script you can post your answers..

```
 cd /DIR/Cars/BMW   
 for f in *.csv
 do
   filename="${f##*/}" 
 echo ${filename}        
      if [[ "${f}" == *c* ]]
         then 
         echo "moving files..."
         mv "${f}" /BMW/c/
       fi
done
cd /DIR/Cars/Mercedes
for f in *.csv
do
  filename="${f##*/}" 
 echo ${filename}     
      if [[ "${f}" == *x* ]]
        then 
       echo "moving files..."
        mv "${f}" /Mercedes/x/
       fi
done
```